# How to find out when the SQL Server was upgraded?

Tags: sql-server

I just inherited a SQL Server (couple of them actually).  The previous DBA is no longer reachable.  The previous DBA also did not maintain a change log.

I myself am not a DBA.  I'm just the closest thing we have at the moment.

As part of my discovery and documentation process, I'd like to note when the SQL Server was upgraded.  I know it was originally a SQL 2008 Server, and is now a SQL 2012 Server.

Is there a t-sql method, or a display in SSMS, that will show me when the upgrade to 2012 happened?

Comment: maybe C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<instanceName>\MSSQL\Log  ?

Answer (score 0):

Using SQLCMD mode you could do something like this:

```
$server = "YouServer"
$srv = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' 
$server
$srv | Select Name,product,ProductLevel,ResourceLastUpdateDateTime
```

I have used this before, got it here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31576/how-to-determine-sql-server-version-install-history-i-e-when-it-was-updated-la

Comment: Thank you @Alan.  That looks like powershell, not SQLCMD.  I've tried running that in powershell and it can't find the correct assembly for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server'.  I'll keep poking at it.

Answer (score -2):

One simple way to do this is to run `SELECT @@version`.

Another option is to right click on the SQL Server instance name in SSMS and select
Properties.

You can also use the **SERVERPROPERTY** function to get details about the version of SQL 
Server.